# DXA 2.0 or DXA 2.2 with SDL Tridion Sites 9 for a new Java project

Tags: 2013-sp1, dxa, dxa-java, sdl-tridion, dxa-2.0

We are about to begin the upgrade of an existing **DXA 1.0 Java** project currently based on **SDL Tridion 2013 SP1**. I know it is not much of an upgrade (moving from DXA Java 1.0 to DXA 2.x), rather it is as good as a new implementation. I would like to know what is advisable from the below 2 options.

1. Implement the website using **SDL Tridion Sites 9** and **DXA 2.0**. Once DXA 2.2 is out & stable upgrade to DXA 2.2.
2. Implement the website using **SDL Tridion Sites 9** and **pre-release DXA 2.2**. Once the GA release is out upgrade to DXA 2.2 GA.

If we are to go with #1 I would like to know if it would be an easy upgrade from DXA 2.0 to DXA 2.2. Your advice and suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: With option#1, I wouldn't expect any(major) issues. With DXA 2.2 of course, you will be able to leverage Tridion Sites 9 features / architecture. 

Just in case, if you haven't seen the following article from Rick, explaning about upgrade paths of different Tridion & DXA versions: 
https://community.sdl.com/product-groups/sdl-tridion-dx/tridion-sites/b/blog-posts/posts/it-s-all-about-versions-dxa-2-0-2-1-2-2-sdl-web-8-sdl-tridion-sites-9-0-and-9-1

Comment: Sounds like a (pretty good) Answer.

Comment: @ShahidEqamuddin thanks for responding. I read Rick's article about DXA versions, however I could not find anything related to upgrade path. The table towards the end of the article explains what additional benefits you get by using DXA 2.0 vs 2.2 and Web 8.x vs Sites 9.

Comment: @RickPannekoek how stable is the current build of DXA Java 2.2? Is it something you would recommend to use for starting a new project and gradually (in about 2 months) upgrade to the GA release?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don’t need to (immediately) use the new Sites 9 architecture/features, I would recommend upgrading to DXA 2.0 first.

The upgrade from DXA 2.0 to 2.2 should be low impact.